# Error accessing external function select - Excel sheet in powerbuilder

Tags: excel, vba, powerbuilder

This is the my script.
Im getting error in select method.
Please help.

Thanks in advance

```
OLEObject      xlApp,xls_1,xls_2
integer            li_rc
string            ls_filepath = "D:\backup\"
xlApp = Create OLEObject
li_rc = xlApp.ConnectToNewObject( "Excel.Application" ) 
if li_rc < 0 then 
      MessageBox("Connect to Excel Failed !",string(li_rc)) 
      Return -1
end if 
xlApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(ls_filepath+'\test1.xls')  
xlApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(ls_filepath+'\test2.xls') 
xls_1 = xlApp.Application.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1]
xls_2 = xlApp.Application.Workbooks[2].Worksheets[1] 
xls_2.activate()
xls_1 .activate()
xls_2.rows("1:8").copy()
xls_1 .Rows("1:8").Select()
xls_1 .paste()
xlApp.Application.workbooks[1].SaveAs(ls_filepath+"\test3.xls") 
xlApp.Application.WorkBooks.close()
xlApp.Application.WorkBooks.Application.quit()
destroy xlApp
destroy xls_1 
destroy xls_2
Return 1
```

Comment: are you getting "invalid spelling" error?

Comment: do not use "select" in your code, btw. refer to ranges by a fully qualified name.

Comment: what color is that line when you are typing in the code?

Comment: color of select method is green in script. Im getting external function error.

Comment: When I am working with 1 excel file, there is no error. But if there are two excel files, i will get error.

Comment: Could the space between xls_1 and .Rows be the problem?

Comment: i removed the space in my script. still the same error.

Comment: Your comment about two excel files (get error) is your hint. When using oleobject 'weakly typed' if everything is not exactly what is expected you'll get errors. I'm guessing that you somehow need to tell the server which one the rows and select statement apply to. I see you have two different oleobjects with different workbooks, I'd study the Excel documentation and see how you differentiate, Or does Excel require activate to occur before each procedure on that workbook/doc/worksheet? Thinking out loud hope it guides you in right direction. Oh, wrapping in TRY CATCH helps with hard crashes.

Comment: I don't know if the ole functions are case sensitive but noticed your line with the select has initcap for Rows & Select. Since it works with one excel file open- probably not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of dynamic objects (weak typing)

These kinds of things require more conscientious development techniques particularly checking the type of object, property, function or whatever your dot nation has navigated you in the neighborhood of.

But some OLE objects are weak on functions to interrogate the entire object model of a dynamic object forcing you to rely heavily on Microsoft OLE documentation which is boring and often version specific. I think your issue would be easier seen by a VBA and/or Visual Basic Scripting or Excel OLE expert.

But in the name of a PowerBuilder solution. It sometimes helps to wrap operations on dynamic objects in **TRY..CATCH..FINALLY** clause and then add your own code to handle the various OLE Exceptions and prevent PB from crashing each time your dot nation doesn't match what was expected.